# LocalDate parse exception

Tags: java-8

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '06/2018' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {Year=2018, MonthOfYear=6},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed

after formatting Date to string and finally want to convert it to LocalDate field getting above exception.

```
String date1 = "14-Jun-18";
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yy");
LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.parse(date1,dateTimeFormatter);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/yyyy");
String s= localDate1.format(formatter);

LocalDate localDate4 = LocalDate.parse(s,formatter);
```

Comment: The 6th month of 2018 isn't a date. LocalDate requires a date.

Comment: you mean Is this invalid ???  ->  LocalDate.parse("06/2018","MM/yyyy");

Comment: Yes, I believe so. It doesn't know which date to parse it to. You may get around it creating a `DateTimeFormatter` using the builder.

Comment: then howcome this one is passed?DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yy");
LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.parse(date1,dateTimeFormatter);

Comment: There's a day there, no? The 14th :)

Answer (score 1):

The JavaDoc on [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) says:

> LocalDate is an immutable date-time object that represents a date, often viewed as year-month-day.

You'll need to either provide with a day, or build a `DateTimeFormatter` using [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) that defaults to a day:

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.time.format.SignStyle;

public class TestDate {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    String date1 = "14-Jun-18";
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yy");
    LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.parse(date1,dateTimeFormatter);

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/yyyy");
    String s = localDate1.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(s);

    DateTimeFormatter formatterWithDefaultDay = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2, 2, SignStyle.NEVER)
        .appendPattern("/")
        .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4, 4, SignStyle.NEVER)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        .toFormatter();

    LocalDate localDateBasedOns = LocalDate.parse(s, formatterWithDefaultDay);
    System.out.println(localDateBasedOns);

  }
}
```

This prints:

```
06/2018
2018-06-01
```